# Looking for a charting Library for JS and React allowing for Zoom

Tags: javascript, charts, react

I am currently rebuilding a previously staic-html+Native js web-page with React. I am therefor looking into different libraries to create a line-chart using Javascript.

The chart was previously created using google-charts but seeing, that my colleagues want to use as few Google tools as possible, I started looking for alternatives.

I have already built, pretty much everything using Chart.js and `react-chartjs-2` but it turns out, that we inevitably need the zooming feature in order to graphically examine slight deviations in the data in the graph, despite there usually being 3000+ entries in a graph that is approx 1000x300px.

I came across `dygraphs` and `react-dygraphs` and though it looks promissing, the last commit is approximately 3 years ago.

Does anyone have experience, as to whether it still works with more current react versions? Is there a (free/open-source) alternative to google-charts, possibly one that I am not aware of?

Libraries I know and excluded are: chart.js, D3, canvasjs

Comment: Just curious as to why you excluded D3js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up up settling for the [React Timeseries Charts](http://software.es.net/react-timeseries-charts/#/) because:

- they are superbly documented, with a LOT of examples
- free to use (under BSD-license),
- offer all the features I am likely to need in the forseeable future (read "ever need")
- and use a [timeseries format](http://software.es.net/pond/#/), which is straightforward and also easy-to-use with python which facilitates implementing the back-end functionality

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the Syncfusion [JavaScript Charts](https://www.syncfusion.com/javascript-ui-controls/charts) library? It has 30+ chart types with [interaction support](https://www.syncfusion.com/javascript-ui-controls/charts/interactive-chart) such as Zoom, pan, trackball, tooltip etc.

Sample link
https://ej2.syncfusion.com/demos/#/material/chart/zooming.html

It also has built-in support for frameworks - Angular, React, Vue

Answer (score 0):

Another option is SciChart's [JavaScript Chart](https://www.scichart.com/javascript-chart-features/).

[image: React Charts - SciChart.js]

They have recently released a [react wrapper](https://www.scichart.com/blog/react-charts-with-scichart-js/) and all the JS Chart demos are in React / Typescript.

SciChart is commercial software but has a [free community edition](https://www.scichart.com/community-licensing/).

*As a disclosure, I work for scichart.*